# Why is the Xamarin.Forms toolbox view empty？

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Visual Studio for Mac 7.0

I'm a new to use the Ide

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUqlh.png)

in the picture，the toolbox is empty。

I entered it by hand

```
 <Button Text="ok"/>
```

No code hints

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is working as expected. There is no visual designer for Xamarin.Forms. XAML must be written manually. You can however use the XAML previewer to assist you.

> The Preview button can be displayed on the editor by right-clicking a
>   XAML file, and selecting Open With > XAML Viewer. The preview pane can
>   then be shown or hidden by pressing the Preview button in the
>   top-right corner of any XAML document window

Information about the previewer can be found here: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/

Comment: hey I am new in xamarin I have Vs2017. It is not showing Xaml Viewer on right click any suggestions please .